# Why does Docker not correctly expose my port when using -P but works with -p 80:80?

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile contains this:

```
EXPOSE 80
```

Yet, if I run the image with `-P` I can't connect to it. Running with `-p 80:80` works fine.

```
danny@linux:~$ sudo docker run -d -P dart-test
               b3277a5483531f6dc23a1c807cf895103fd5333b603c1b4a352e07c9721f1a48

# Can't connect here
danny@linux:~$ curl http://localhost/
               curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

danny@linux:~$ sudo docker stop b3277
               b3277

danny@linux:~$ sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 dart-test
               dfe68699bfb33ce33e8e6e1953ac828b9d31209988df64e2627d9228758438ba

# Connects fine here
danny@linux:~$ curl http://localhost/
               Hello, world!

danny@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `-P`, docker will bind the exposed port to a random high port from the range 49153 to 65535 on the docker host. To determine the actual port, you'll need to run

```
docker port <CONTAINER> 80
```

When you use `-p 80:80`, you specifically bind the exposed port to the host's port 80.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I read [the docs here](http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/) but can't see any mention of using random ports; it reads like it would just open the same ports that were `EXPOSE`d?

Comment: The docs are not very clear on this, but this info is available in some parts. See http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#network-port-mapping-refresher

Comment: Right; ta :) Seems like the docs I linked should be updated to mention this there; is quite confusing!

Comment: Docker docs are in GitHub here: https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/docs and [pull requests are very welcome](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contribution-guidelines).

Comment: @Andy, I've already made a pull request for this - https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/8123